# How to find first local maxima in an unknown dataframe

Tags: python

I get a Dataframe in Python with multiple maxima and minima, I want to find always the first maxima/minima in the frame and ignore the other ones. The problem is that the data has a lot of noise and the datapoints come at different values, so I can not set a certain numerical threshold value. How do I go about this?

[image: local maxima]

Comment: Denoising should be certainly done at the very beginning. Could you provide more details about the signal and the noise or just upload some data? How did you get these data, from what kind of sensors?

Comment: It could be detrimental to separate smoothing and peak finding. Being able to incorporate both actions on the same algorithm could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), they implement the heuristics you probably would come up with and expose parameters you can tweak accordingly to the characteristic of your signal.